# Paypal Integration using vue, axios and laravel api throws 500 internal error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, paypal, payment

I am making a paypal integration webapp using vue and laravel api. Whenever i trigger post method it shows internal server error 500. Whenever i trigger post method using axios it only catches the error and doesnot complete the functionality i provided. I also dont know to use csrf token in vue . Anyone who can help me with this.

My Vue Code:

```
    PayForPaypal() {
if(this.$refs.form.validate() === true){

  let payPalData = {
    price: this.plansData.price,
    name: this.plansData.name,
  }

  axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/payokay", payPalData, {
    headers:{
    
    }
  }).then(res=>{
    console.log(res);
  }).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
  })
} 
    },
```

My laravel code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
        $item_1 = new Item();

        $item_1->setName($request->name)
            ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setPrice($request->price);

        $item_list = new ItemList();
        $item_list->setItems(array($item_1));

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setTotal($request->price);
        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($item_list)
            ->setDescription('Awebly ' . $request->name);

        $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl('http://localhost:8080/Plans')
            ->setCancelUrl('http://localhost:8080/Plans');

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('Sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
        try {
            $payment->create($this->_api_context);

            $payment_details = new PaymentDetail();
            $payment_details->payment_method = 'Paypal';
            $payment_details->plan = $request->name;
            $payment_details->payment_id = $payment->getId();
            $payment_details->amount = $request->price;
            $payment_details->user_name = auth()->user()->name;
            $payment_details->user_id=auth()->user()->id;
            $payment_details->save();
        } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
            DB::rollBack();
            if (Config::get('app.debug')) {
                return response(
                    [
                        'message'=>'connection timeout'
                    ]
                );
            } else {
                return response(
                    [
                        'message'=>'error'
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
        DB::commit();

        foreach ($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
            if ($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
                $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isset($redirect_url)) {
            return redirect($redirect_url);
        }
        return response(
            [
                'message'=>'unknown error occurred'
            ]
        );

    }
```

I dont know what is the mistake. Any help are appreciated.

Comment: in laravel code i forget to mention Request $request in store function.

Comment: Do you have a Laravel log file, normally the error should be logged there.

Comment: @Aless55 No sir i cannot even hit that api. Whenever i trigger that function same error occurs.